# How to ask "is it really so that..."?

Tags: grammar, expressions

How do I ask a question like "is it really so that you're just 18?" or "is it really so that the movie was good?", i.e. a surprised question?

My guess is something along the lines of "这是真的，你只有十八岁呢?", but it sounds weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds weird because there is no formal subject (A.K.A. anticipatory subject) in Chinese. `It is [X] that [Y]` should be transformed into `[Y][verb as appropriate][X]` during translation。For example:

```
It is a pleasure to meet you. =>
Meeting you is a pleasure. =>
见到你很高兴。
```

So for the original sentence,

```
Is it really so that you're just 18? =>
Are you really just 18? =>
你真的只有18岁？
```

Comment: An alternate expression: "你**当真**只有18岁？"

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, "is it really so that…?" should be translate to "...真的...吗？".

The First sentence shuold be "你**真的**只有18岁**吗**？";

And the second should be "这部电影**真的**好看**吗**？".

Comment: Why "你**真的**只有" becomes "你*真的*只有"(只有 is displayed in italics). I must type a space after 你 and before 只有 in order to get bold style correctly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to this site! As for your question, I've suffered it too, but the moderator Alenanno gave me a good solution-just use the html tag <Strong>words</Strong> to make the words in bold.

Comment: Yes, the <Strong> mark worked. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes, the same structure does not mean the same way of translate.

for this question, i will translate as follow

is it really so that you're just 18?
你只有18岁？真的假的！

is it really so that the movie was good?
你确定这部电影还行？

Answer (score 0):

The way I've had Chinese people express surprise to me is to use 这么. For example:

`你是18岁？这么年轻！看不出来！`

I realize that this is different than the sentence structure that you gave (and that NS.X. helped clarify) but I find that in my interactions with Chinese, they're more apt to follow their question of disbelief with an exclamation describing their reaction in order to express their surprise.

Comment: 你是18岁 sounds awkward. Maybe “你才18岁”？